# How can I combine edges in an ortho graph?

Tags: graphviz

I'm using `splines=ortho` and I was hoping for the edges to collapse together. To illustrate, I want to accomplish this:

[image]

I tried this:

```
digraph G {
  splines=ortho;

  edge [dir=none];
  node [shape=diamond, label="", height=0.1, width=0.1];

  start -> a [weight=10];
  start -> b;
  start -> c;
  start -> d;
  start -> e;
}
```

But it ends up looking like this:

[image]

Any clue on how I can make the edges overlap each other?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446775/node-placement-in-family-tree-visualization-with-dot-graphviz/33451324#33451324) for how ro use empty nodes

Answer (score 1):

You need to create empty nodes on the same level as `start` and connect to them first, then draw the rest of your graph:

```
digraph G
{  
  node[ shape = point, label="", height=0, width=0 ] 01 02 03 04; 
  node[ shape=diamond, label="", height=0.1, width=0.1 ];
  { rank = same; start 01 02 03 04; }

  edge [dir=none];
  start -> 01 -> 02 -> 03 -> 04[ minlen = 2 ];
  start -> a [weight=2];
  01 -> b;
  02 -> c;
  03 -> d;
  04 -> e;
}
```

yields

[image: ![enter image description here]